# Unable to install iOS 9.3 beta Profile

Tags: ios, beta-seed-program, iphone

After installing iOS beta 10 and then downgrading again to 9.3 standard with clean install, it seems that I can't install the profile for iOS 9.3 Public Beta via apple beta program.

After touching on the link with iPhone 6S Plus, the phone returns an error.

No profiles is installed at the moment.

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple warns against switching profiles for this reason.

You could try to remove any lingering profiles that could be getting in the way by connecting your phone to a Mac (if you have one). Then in Xcode (you might have to install), go to Windows > Devices. From there, you can manage the installed profiles and delete any that might be causing a conflict.

Also, be sure you are doing everything correctly. This guide should be of help: http://www.imore.com/how-download-ios-93-public-beta

Comment: I will try that and I will let you know about the result. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer if this helped you with your problem, or you can always ask more questions via the comments. Just letting you know because you're new...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's because their profile is expired. Hurry and go download the latest iOS 9.3.3 pb 5 ipsw from https://m.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/4rldc6/official_apple_ipsw_links_for_ios_933_beta_5/ so it doesn't expire on you. I had to do this and used shift+check for update in iTunes. Worked perfectly. And this should get you to the public release.